# PostgresSQL создать новые записи в таблице по аналогии с существующими

Tags: postgresql

Имеем две основных таблицы
Из одной интересует пара значений (таких пар значений с одинаковым тайтлом, но разными типами много)

```
//fields
     id | title | type
--------+-------+-------
      1 |  some |  one
      2 |  some |  two
      3 | thing |  one
      4 | thing |  two
```

Во второй таблице содержится запись по значению с первым типом

```
//service
     id | field_id | service_id | some_id
--------+----------+------------+---------
      1 |        1 |        321 |     987
      2 |        3 |        123 |     654
```

Связаны таблицы через fields.id = service.field_id

И вот мне требуется во второй таблице создать записи для всех значений из первой таблицы с типом two и значениями service_id и some_id как у записи с типом one и таким же title.

То есть выходная таблица service должна получиться такой:

```
//service
     id | field_id | service_id | some_id
--------+----------+------------+---------
      1 |        1 |        321 |     987
      2 |        3 |        123 |     654
      3 |        2 |        321 |     987
      4 |        4 |        123 |     654
```

Я смог только написать запрос который по итогу заносит мне множество значений создавая записи со всеми значениями из первой таблицы с типом two и с каждым возможным значением service_id и some_id из второй...

Comment: Раз 10 перечитал предложение с "что требуется" так ничего и не понял. Во первых упростите вопрос, раз уже умеете вставлять записи на основе другой выборки (т.е. делать insert select). Суть вопроса явно связана только с написанием правильного select для этого insert. Во вторых расширьте пример, что бы в нем было представлено больше записей и напишите пример какие именно записи должны получиться на выходе (т.е. которые должны быть добавлены) на основании приведенных данных. Так же не помешало бы указать как именно связаны эти две таблицы (я конечно подозреваю что 2.field_id=1.id)